# WebRtc from a raspberry pi running windows 10 iot

Tags: raspberry-pi, uwp, signalr, webrtc, webcam

The goal is to create a remote webcam using Windows 10 IOT on a raspberry Pi with a webcam attached.

The raspberry pi is controlled using signalR on a webapi, this can control the GPIO pins on the device, and make calls to the device to submit required information ( a kind of 'pull' message!!) BUT it would be great to also view the webcam attached to the device. This would open up some amazing applications for windows 10 IOT on a raspberry pi, at a very low cost.

The webcam is attached successfully because The web application can request it to post a photo remotely via a webapi call which triggers a signalR call to the client UWP application on the raspberry pi. The photo can then be viewed on a web page.

The UWP app on the Pi should be able to stream it's webcam.

webRTC would be a great way to achieve this.

There is a webRTC for UWP library available so it should be possible to create a webRTC client.

First step is to setup mediacapture on startup 'automagically'!!, is that even possible?

Once that is achieved it could post the connection details to my server which should be able to make the stream available via a webpage.

Comment: "First step is to setup mediacapture on startup..." Do you mean that if there is an app can auto run on startup, open the webcam and start capturing?

Comment: yes, so the app is running on the IOT device, in this case a raspbarry PI, but it could be any device running windows 10 IOT. Therefore the app would be a UWP either running in the background or foreground. Let's assume it is running in the foreground. In this case the app would at some point connect to the webcam via the mediacapture call in webRTC. Normally this results in a prompt to the user for confirmation, however I would like to be automatic